# appending a line after there is match for 2 pattern in Unix shell scripting

Tags: perl, unix, sed, awk

I have a file like

```
nithin shetty
sachin shetty
pavan shetty
```

In this file i want to append "HELLO THIS IS ME",next line to the pattern "shetty". But the condition is that if the line matches for "nithin" , then don't append the line.
I know how to append a line after a pattern match,

```
sed '/shetty/a\
  HELLO THIS IS ME
' filename`
```

But in this i don't want a line containing `nithin`. Output should be like this:

```
nithin shetty
sachin shetty
  HELLO THIS IS ME
pavan shetty
  HELLO THIS IS ME
```

Is it possible??

Comment: Are the backticks really in the file?

Answer (score 3):

A `sed` solution would be of the form:

```
sed '/nithin/b; /shetty/a\ HELLO THIS IS ME' filename
```

`b` would cause sed to branch to the end of the script in the absence of a label.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't know `sed`, but I do know Perl.

```
perl -nE'print; say "HELLO THIS IS ME" if /shetty/ && !/nithin/'
```

or

```
perl -pe'$_ .= "HELLO THIS IS ME\n" if /shetty/ && !/nithin/'
```

Like with `sed`,

- Lines will be read from the named file(s) or from stdin if no files are named.
- Output will be sent to stdout.
- You can use `-i` for in-place editing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it with `awk`:

```
awk '!/nithin/ && /shetty/ { $0 = $0 "\n  HELLO THIS IS ME" } 1' infile
```

Output:

```
nithin shetty
sachin shetty
  HELLO THIS IS ME
pavan shetty
  HELLO THIS IS ME
```